# Сортировка по алфавиту (с++)

Tags: c++, сортировка

Нужно отсортировать массив слов по алфавиту, (честно лазил, пытался вникнуть, но с указателями не дружу) Проблема в том, что я не могу понять как сравнить char в массиве строк (выдавал ошибку). Еще выдает ошибку Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char **mass = new char *[8];


    for(int i = 0; i<7;i++) {
        mass[i] = new char[20];
        cin >> mass[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 7; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j < 8; i++)
            if(strcpy(mass[i], mass[j]) > 0){
                char* tmp = mass[i];
                mass[i] = mass[j];
                mass[j] = tmp;
            }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        cout << mass[i] << endl;
    }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy` копирует строки, а нужно, `strcmp`, чтобы их сравнить - это первая ошибка.

Comment: Вы считываете всего 7 строк, а у вас, как я понял из контекста, их 8 - это вторая ошибка.

Comment: Во втором цикле вместо `i++` должно быть `j++` - это третья. У меня сложилось ощущение, что вы просто пошутили и решили проверить, кто найдёт все опечатки : )

Comment: извините, просто целый день пытаюсь разные варианты этой сортировки применить, к концу дня уже голова не варит(

Comment: используйте `std::cin`, `std::cout` для ввода-вывода, а для хранения слов - `std::string` - они гораздо более удобны и безопасны, чем работа напрямую с массива char[]

Comment: ещё в конце забыто delete [] mass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcpy` копирует строки, а нужно, `strcmp`, чтобы их сравнить - это первая ошибка.

Вы считываете всего 7 строк, а у вас, как я понял из контекста, их 8 - это вторая ошибка.

Во втором цикле вместо `i++` должно быть `j++` - это третья.

Исправьте все три ошибки, что я указал - и должно работать.

Comment: Да! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Поставьте, пожалуйста, "галочку", что ответ засчитан : )

Comment: Боюсь, что обсуждение в комментариях тут не приветствуется. Если хотите, чтобы вам разъяснили ваш код, лучше задать другой вопрос и чётко указать, что вы хотите. А этот вопрос как бы закрыт.

Comment: хорошо а как это реализовать в классе?